# Errors while building LLVM

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cmake, clang, llvm

Building llvm on ubuntu 18.04 virtual machine, faced an error while running make on the step 7 of the tutorial(Build LLVM and Clang). The stacktrace attached. Help please!

> **[ 49%] Building ASM object projects/compiler-rt/lib/xray/CMakeFiles/RTXray.x86_64.dir/xray_trampoline_x86_64.S.o
>   cc: error: unrecognized argument to -fno-sanitize= option: ‘safe-stack’
>   cc: error: unrecognized debug output level ‘line-tables-only’
>   projects/compiler-rt/lib/xray/CMakeFiles/RTXray.x86_64.dir/build.make:206: recipe for target 'projects/compiler-rt/lib/xray/CMakeFiles/RTXray.x86_64.dir/xray_trampoline_x86_64.S.o' failed
>   make[2]:**  [projects/compiler-rt/lib/xray/CMakeFiles/RTXray.x86_64.dir/xray_trampoline_x86_64.S.o] Error 1
>   CMakeFiles/Makefile2:29096: recipe for target 'projects/compiler-rt/lib/xray/CMakeFiles/RTXray.x86_64.dir/all' failed
>   make[1]:  **[projects/compiler-rt/lib/xray/CMakeFiles/RTXray.x86_64.dir/all] Error 2
>   Makefile:151: recipe for target 'all' failed
>   make: *** [all] Error 2**

Comment: Are you building the latest version of LLVM?

Comment: I am aware of "line-tables-only" option being available in clang-6.0, and in my Ubuntu 16.04 I used "sudo apt-get install clang-6.0 clang++-6.0" to install clang-6.0.   Do  that and make again with "CC=clang-6.0 CXX=clang++-6.0 make".  It should work.